# Airpods choppy on Windows Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, imac, airpods

I recently booted up Windows 10 using Bootcamp on my iMac.  However, when I tried to use my Airpods, the sound quality is choppy.  It's fine for a second or two, and then cuts out for about a quarter of a second, and it keeps going like this.  The Airpods work completely fine on the MacOS side of my iMac, so it's not the Airpods' problem.  Can someone be of assistance?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Found a solution.  I removed all other Bluetooth devices and it works.